# Request URI too large for Grafana - kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

We are running nearly 100 instances in Production for kubernetes cluster and using prometheus server to create Grafana dashboard. To monitor the disk usage , below query is used

```
(sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance=~"$Instance"}) - sum(node_filesystem_free_bytes{instance=~"$Instance"})) / sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance=~"$Instance"})
```

As Instance ip is getting replaced and we are using nearly 80 instances, I am getting error as "Request URI too large".Can someone help to fix this issue

Comment: How many instances is there in your `=~"$Instance"`. 100 is not a lot but it is used 3 times  and names can be long ; that can add up. Can't you have another criteria ? Is your prometheus behind a http service (apache, nginx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to specify the instances once and use the [`on` matching operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) to get their matching series:

```
(sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance=~"$Instance"})
  - on(instance) sum(node_filesystem_free_bytes))
/ on(instance) sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes)
```

Consider also adding a unifying label to your time series so you can do something like `...{instance_type="group-A"}` instead of explicitly specifying instances.